# log4j2 log file created even when Level is OFF?

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I have a global logger which is used in a few classes so that I can log everything in a single file. All works good, however I want to be able to disable the Logger from UI. I tried setting the Level to OFF like shown below, which stops the logging but an empty log file is still created ( I am using File Appender with the logger).

Is there any easy way to avoid creating the log file when Level is OFF ?

```
public class Main {
    public static Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger("GLOBAL");
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configurator.setLevel("GLOBAL", Level.OFF);
        //Rest of code

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LogManager.getLogger("GLOBAL")` creates the log file while reading the log4j configuration and initializing it. So, there is no way you can stop it from doing it when you are at `Configurator.setLevel("GLOBAL", Level.OFF);`. IMO, you have 2 options:

1) **Elegant way**: Initialize the LogManager in your code by passing the configuration at runtime `LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration`. You could refer [here](http://www.nailedtothex.org/roller/kyle/entry/java-util-logging-programmatic-configuration) for detailed implementation.

2) **Ugly way**: Delete the log file when you set the LEVEL.OFF

Comment: I am trying to avoid making changes to files etc. How would I pass the configuration on runtime ? <code>LogManager.getLogManager() </code> this method doesn't seem to be part of log4j.LogManager. I am currently using log4j2.xml for configs and I have found I few ways to edit the configuration on runtime but all of them seem overkill for what I am trying to achieve

Comment: First of all, why are you concerned that the file is there when the level is turned off? I wouldn't worry about it personally. I agree its a overkill for what you are trying to do. If that's the way you want it, look at an example here http://www.nailedtothex.org/roller/kyle/entry/java-util-logging-programmatic-configuration

Comment: Yea, that is getting overcomplicated, I think I will just delete the file for now...